# Update Autodesk Docs / BIM360 document metadata using Forge .Net SDK

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

I cannot find anything in [forge sdk](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-client) to achieve setting metadata / custom attributes on an uploaded item/document.
Is it simply not there?

If so, are there other ways of achieving this for both BIM360 and Autodesk Docs documents?

Answer (score 0):

For the BIM360/ACC specific endpoints, you would need to use .NET REST requests (e.g. RestSharp)

Comment: sorry, brain malfunction :-)